# Re-post in asp.net with updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, postback, partial-postback, repost

I have a page with events included in **update panel**, others not included in the update panel. I want to prevent repost **action** in the page. 
whats the best way to do that with handling **partail** and **full postback** ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using UpdatePanel Triggers:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers